# Run function when two Backbone collection fetch's finish

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have an app that upon start needs to load from the server a list of users, and privilege groups.

This is what I have so far:

```
userApp.AppRouter = new (Backbone.Router.extend
startApp: ->
    self = @

    @users = new userApp.UserCollection()
    @users.fetch({
        success: (data, response) ->
            # Need to find a way to make drawApp be called when this and the other fetch finish
        error: (data, response) ->
            console.log( "Error fetching users" )
        })

    @privGroups = new userApp.GroupCollection()
    @privGroups.fetch({
        success: (data, response) ->
            self.drawApp()
        error: (data, response) ->
            console.log( "Error fetching groups" )
            console.log( data )
            console.log( response )
        })

drawApp: ->
    userManager = new userApp.App(@users, @privGroups)
```

)

right now i'm just calling the drawApp function when the privGroup finishes fetching because usually it is done second, but not always. I want to have when both are finished, it calls drawApp. I am thinking this will include over-riding Backbone.Sync in some way to use the [jQuery.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to override sync to use `when` since fetch already returns a jQuery promise.

```
fetchingUsers = @users.fetch()
fetchingGroups = @privGroups.fetch()

$.when(fetchingUsers, fetchingGroups).done(() -> 
    self.drawApp()
)
```

Hope the coffee script is right.

Answer (score 1):

Paul's answer is correct.  A nice bit of Coffee sugar would be to use the [Fat Arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) to bind the done method to the outer scope.

CoffeeScript:

```
$.when(fetchingUsers, fetchingGroups).done => @drawApp
```

Resulting Javascript:

```
var _this = this;

$.when(fetchingUsers, fetchingGroups).done(function() {
  return _this.drawApp();
});
```